# Hide mouse-over comments in Google Maps embed code

Tags: wordpress, comments, maps, embed

I have a question concerning Google Maps. On the contact page of a website I did include Google Maps. Unfortunately, when a user hovers (mouse over) over the pin on the map, a comment about a nearby restaurant is also shown. And more unfortunate, the comment is bad :P. How can I hide this functionality from the map?

See http://bullseyemedia.nl/contact and hover over the A.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Reinder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a static map, very easy to code.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/